# JavaScript rescursive XML element traversal

Tags: javascript, xml, algorithm, recursion, traversal

My intention is to find all the "text nodes" of a given xml using a recursive means, so for example if input xml was:

```
    <foo>
        <bar>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </bar>
    </foo>
```

then i want to find `<a>` and `<b>` after which i pass them to a different function. The code i'm using to find the nodes of interest is below:

```
    xml = $.parseXML(MY_INPUT_XML);
    nodesOfInterest = [];
    var depthFirstTraversal = function ($root, callback) {
        $root.children().each(function () {
            depthFirstTraversal($(this), callback);
        });
        callback($root);
    };

    depthFirstTraversal($(xml).children(), function ($node) {
        if ($node[0].childElementCount === 0) { //if it has no children then i want to store it
            nodesOfInterest.push($node);                                                    
        }
    });
```

The above works as expected in most cases but it fails if the parent nodes have some attributes or xsi types. for example if below is my input xml:

```
    <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <buyGuid>
                <Context>
                    <INFO>
                        <buyGuidRequest>
                            <Property xsi:type="PostalAddress">
                                <address>Some address</address>
                                <postcode>0000</postcode>
                            </Property>
                        </buyGuidRequest>
                    </INFO>
                </Context>
            </buyGuid>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

It doesn't traverse to children of `<buyGuidRequest>` or `<Property>`!! However if i remove the `xsi:type` from `<Property>` tag it correctly traverse to all chidlren of Property and finds Address and zipCode. I don't undrestand why this is happening and how xsi:type is affecting the depth traversal? Can someone please shed some light on this issue? Thanks

Comment: What is `xml`, a string or a document? Do you need to use jQuery?

Comment: @Bergi i've updated the code but `xml` was referring to `xml = $.parseXML(MY_INPUT_XML);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your input is malformed and it won't recognize the xsi prefix. That behavior is reproduced when removing the attribute

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

from the element

> <soap:Body>

[This works](http://jsbin.com/lorizuya/1/edit?js,console)

```
 <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <buyGuid>
                <Context>
                    <INFO>
                        <buyGuidRequest>
                            <Property xsi:type="PostalAddress">
                                <address>Some address</address>
                                <postcode>0000</postcode>
                            </Property>
                        </buyGuidRequest>
                    </INFO>
                </Context>
            </buyGuid>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

[This doesn't work](http://jsbin.com/qexeyuze/1/edit?js,console)

```
 <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <buyGuid>
                <Context>
                    <INFO>
                        <buyGuidRequest>
                            <Property xsi:type="PostalAddress">
                                <address>Some address</address>
                                <postcode>0000</postcode>
                            </Property>
                        </buyGuidRequest>
                    </INFO>
                </Context>
            </buyGuid>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

[This works](http://jsbin.com/cugoboja/1/)

```
 <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <buyGuid>
                <Context>
                    <INFO>
                        <buyGuidRequest>
                            <Property>
                                <address>Some address</address>
                                <postcode>0000</postcode>
                            </Property>
                        </buyGuidRequest>
                    </INFO>
                </Context>
            </buyGuid>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```